# Problems piping a file list to emacs

Tags: bash, emacs, xargs

I'm trying to pipe the output of ack (like grep) to emacs to edit a bunch of files.  Running in an ssh window with no graphics I get this:

```
 #>  ack findit -l
 file1
 file2
 file3
 #>  ack findit -l | xargs emacs
 emacs: standard input is not a tty#>
```

I have no problems launching emacs on its own.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Additional info: if I run xargs --verbose I can copy and paste the printed command and it works fine.

```
strong text
```

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `emacsclient`? That works for me with

```
ack . *.c -l | xargs emacsclient -nw -a ''
```

to open all the `.c` files for example.